# How to change the font color of the checkout coupon input text?

Tags: php, wordpress, text, colors, coupon

When someone starts typing the coupon the text will not be visible since the color is white
I want to change to black or dark grey

I'm referring to the input text at checkout and not the cart page,
try to add a product then type coupon and see what I mean `
My site: https://shareefsaadi.com/

[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJTNK.jpg)

https://shareefsaadi.com/checkout/

Thanks `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code in your custom css sections

```
.woocommerce-page.woocommerce-checkout div.coupon .input-text {
    color: red;
}
```

replace red with your color code

Comment: When you know Code stuff it sounds so easy haha
I've been trying to figure out from inspect elements page to find the right code ^^"
Thanks a lot, I appreciate that `